# Как создать простой текстовой файл в Делфи?

Tags: delphi, файлы, текст, delphi-xe5

Мне нужно создать простой текстовый файл в Делфи и записать в него буквально пару строк. Как это сделать максимально просто?

Например, создать `1.txt` по пути `D:\folder\` с содержимым `123456` и `777`.

Comment: Это перевод вопроса https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51746448

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наиболее распространенный вариант, через `TStringList`:

```
procedure MakeTextFile;
var
  sl: TStringList;
begin
  sl := TStringList.Create;
  try
    sl.Add('123456');
    sl.Add('777');
    sl.SaveToFile('D:\folder\1.txt');
  finally
    sl.Free
  end;
end;
```

Также, можно использовать `TFile` (из модуля `IOUtils`):

```
fn := 'D:\folder\1.txt';

// Вариант 1 - указываем все содержимое сразу в виде массива
TFile.WriteAllLines(fn, ['123456', '777']);

// Вариант 2 - указываем все содержимое сразу одной строкой
TFile.WriteAllText(fn, '123456' + sLineBreak + '777');

// Вариант 3 - добавляем содержимое по частям
TFile.WriteAllText(fn, '123456');
TFile.AppendAllText(fn, sLineBreak);
TFile.AppendAllText(fn, '777');
```

Comment: + за вариант с TFile. Он по умолчанию работает с UTF-8 и записывает BOM. А вот SL по умолчанию работает с TEncoding.Default, который (емнип) ANSI. Соответственно - BOM не пишется и может стать больно... Т.е. для SL желательно принудительно указывать кодировку.

Comment: @kami про BOM хороший комментарий, спасибо! Собственно я перевод с enSO из-за `TFile` и сделал - сам не ожидал, что можно *так* просто )

Comment: Я бы ещё указал использование TStreamWriter как самый быстрый способ. Понятно, что записать " 123456 и 777" не требует скорости, но noblesse oblige

Comment: @kami TEncoding.Default не всегда ANSI и даже не на MacOS системах

Answer (score 1):

Максимально просто старым добрым способом

```
procedure DoItClassic;
var 
  F: TextFile;
begin
  AssignFile (F, 'D:\folder\1.txt');
  ReWrite (F);
  writeln (F, '12345');
  CloseFile (F);
end;
```